# getSeconds() and minute rollover

Tags: javascript

How does `Date()` handle rollover?

Say you call `getMinute()` and it return 10. You call `getSecond()` and it returns 0. Is that because the time is second 0 of minute 10, or because between the two calls the clock rolled over to a new minute and it's not second zero of minute 11?

Is there a prescribed way to handle this in JS?

If not, is there a better solution than usual trick of repeatedly reading all the values until they match?

Comment: Also is it me or are all the UTC functions broken because they don't support leap seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that because the time is second 0 of minute 10...

Yes.

> ...or because between the two calls the clock rolled over to a new minute and it's not second zero of minute 11?

No. :-)

The time in a `Date` instance doesn't change unless you change it. You can safely read the hours, then the minutes, then the seconds, and know that they all are as they were when you created or last modified that date instance.

When you create a `Date` instance, it stores a "time value" which is the number of milliseconds since The Epoch, which is midnight on January 1st 1970 GMT. (`Date` instances for dates prior to that have a negative time value, ones since have a positive one.) That time value is never changed unless you change it via one of `Date`'s mutator methods (`setHours`, etc.).

Here's a live example showing the fact that it doesn't change in action:

```js
// This grabs a `Date` instance for right now
let d = new Date();

// That date instance stores the "time value"
console.log(d.valueOf() + " is " + d.toISOString());

// Even if we wait a bit, we still see the same value
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(d.valueOf() + " is " + d.toISOString());
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It seems that conversion to ISO format correctly handles leap seconds too.

Comment: @user11567957 - Glad that helped! Note that the ISO stuff was just a convenient way to show all the fields. Not sure what you mean about it "handling" leap seconds. JavaScript dates [*don't* handle leap seconds](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range), and nothing about [`toISOString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) tries to adjust that (it couldn't, really).

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand what's possible with the `Date` object make it refresh multiple times per second. And place your needed properties in an output field. I am adding this because for many purposes the `getTime()` is the most exact time reference because it includes milliseconds. From this you can always calculate back to minutes, hours or days in various ways.

Below some examples to help you in the future:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('time-var-output');
const snippetStartT = (new Date()).getTime();

const echoTime = function (){
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.getTime();
  element.value = 'getTime(): '+time+"\n";
  element.value += 'seconds.ms: '+(time/1000)+"\n";
  element.value += 'seconds: '+parseInt(time/1000)+"\n";
  element.value += 'minutes: '+parseInt(time/1000/60)+"\n";
  element.value += 'hours: '+parseInt(time/1000/60/60)+"\n"; 
  element.value += 'days: '+parseInt(time/1000/60/60/24)+"\n"; 
  element.value += 'seconds after start: '+parseInt((time-snippetStartT)/1000)+"\n";
  element.value += 'UTC-Date: '+date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
}

window.setInterval(echoTime,(1000/20)) // refresh 20 times per second
```

```html
<div id="developer-output">&nbsp;output:<br>
 <textarea id="time-var-output" cols="32" rows="10" readonly='true'></textarea>
</div>
```